# C# WPF How to navigate to an existing page from the MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, nullreferenceexception

I have a task which has to implement the MVVM pattern.
I have a MainWindow with a button, successfully tied it up to a working and tested command. 
My goal is to navigate to an existing Page on button click, but the problem is:

-NullReferenceException()

Corresponding MainWindow.xaml part

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Content="{Binding MainFrame}" ></Frame>
ETC
```

Corresponding ViewModels clickCommand:

```
private void ExecuteMethod(object parameter)
    {
        View.Home homePage = new View.Home();
        mainFrame.Content = homePage;
        MainFrame.Navigate(homePage);
    }
```

Page to be loaded is an existing page with several controls in it, yet I fail to even navigate to there, since

```
mainFrame.Content = homePage;
```

throws a NullReferenceException(object reference not set to an instance of an object)

What am I missing?

Comment: You are using the MainFrame class. Use the proper case to use the variable i/o the class. `mainFrame`. Not `MainFrame`. Not really sure but seems like the issue here

Comment: To navigate use 'FrameContent.Navigate(new MyPage()); '